# Attempting to stimulate page to produce server sent event with POST data from another page not working

Tags: php, http, curl, post, php-curl

When I open update.php on its own (with self supplied test vars), it sends the SSE to testsse.php just fine and there are no issues (Everything I need to be printed is showing up in inspect element), However, I am trying to have POST data from another page (In this case mootssetest.php) get received by update.php so it may send out the SSE containing the data. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but this test rig is not working. Guidance would be appreciated.
testsse.php (front end page meant to receive SSE and print)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Using Server-Sent Events</title>
<script>
            window.onload = function() {
            var link = new EventSource("update.php");
            var antispam;
            var inputthing = event.data;
            var splitted;
            link.onmessage = function(event) {
                inputthing = event.data;
                splitted = inputthing.split(" ");
                if (splitted[0] != antispam && splitted[1] == <?php echo $page; ?>) {
                    document.getElementById("livemsg").innerHTML += "<div id=\"post-" + splitted[0] + "\" class=\"reply\">" + "</div>";
                    antispam = splitted[0];
        };
    };
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="livemsg">
        <!--Server response will be inserted here-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

update.php (SSE sender, post receiver)

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$postnum = $data[0];
$bread = $data[1];
postnum = 32;
bread = 4;
function liveupdate($postnum, $bread) 
    {
    header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
    echo "data: " .  $postnum . " " . $bread . "\n\n";
    flush();
    }

liveupdate($postnum, $bread);
?>
```

mootssetest.php (POST sender)

```
function httppost($postnum, $bread)
{
    $url = "http://localhost/update.php";
    $data = array($postnum, $bread);
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    $jsondata = json_encode($data);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsondata );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

httppost(420, 4);
?>
```

(For context, I am trying to have this print a new post in some forum software every time a function is called without refreshing the page for the user)

Answer (score 0):

you haven't included the event in your window.onload() function, please fix it first and try again.